# Xlosure subsets of a metric space X

Tags: real-analysis

If A and B are subsets of a metric space X, then cl(A ∩ B)= cl(A)∩ cl(B)

Why is it false??

but it is true when it is AuB.

Comment: Take a look at my solution if it makes sense to prove that it's false. The set cl(a)∩ cl(b) is a closed set which contains a∩b and so it also contains cl(a∩b). For instance a=(0,1) and b=(1,2) then a∩b= empty set and cl(a∩b)=empty set while cl(a)∩ cl(b)={1}. Therefore, false

Comment: right? is there different way of solving this? w/o giving a counterexample?

Comment: Well, not really, in general, a statement is false **iff** there is a counterexample.

Comment: since i have shown my counterexample, then my answer is valid. correct?

Comment: Yes, any counterexample will suffice.

Comment: thank you. i wanted to sure make that my counterexample is correct so that i could prove it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Because the intersection may be empty.

$A=\{0\}, B=(0,1)$. Then $\overline{A \cap B} = \emptyset$, but
$\overline{A} \cap \overline{B} = \{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

two classes of simple counterexamples are

(1) suppose $A$ is any countable dense subset of an uncountable space $X$ and $B$ is a subset of the complement of $A$

(2) consider the trivial topology on any set $X$ of infinite cardinality. the empty set is its own closure, but the closure of any non-empty set is $X$

the common misapprehension pointed out by OP perhaps arises because we become used to thinking of union and intersection as dual notions. this may be true in the context of boolean lattices, but it is not true when we consider the behaviour of non-injective mappings. and this is relevant to topology.

the usual way to define a topology on $X$ amounts to saying which subsets of $X$ are open - or, which amounts to the same thing, which sets are closed.

however you can also define a topology on $X$ in terms of a **closure operator**. this is an endomorphism $\kappa$ of $\mathfrak{P}(X)$ (the power set of $X$) which satisfies $\kappa(\emptyset)=\emptyset$ and the requirements:

$$
\forall A \in \mathfrak{P}(X). A \subset \kappa(A) \tag{monotone}
$$
$$
\kappa^2 = \kappa \tag{idempotent}
$$
$$
\kappa(\cup_{j=1,...,n}) A_j = \cup_{j=1,...,n} \tag{finite union} \kappa(A_j)
$$
the closed sets of the topology on $X$ defined by such a $\kappa$ are precisely the $\kappa$-stable subsets of $X$

note that for any map $\phi$ between sets the condition 
$$
\phi(A \cap B) = \phi (A) \cap \phi(B)
$$
can only be guaranteed for all $A,B$ if $\phi$ is a monomorphism